# Taking the $j-th$ component of a covariant derivative and the covariant derivative of $j-th$ component

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative, tensors

Generally, one defines the expression $\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j}$ by :

$$\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j} \;\equiv\; (\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j}$$

(with $X_{i}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$)

so when we calculate $\nabla_{X_{i}}V=\left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j}$, it is easy to note what the $j-$th component is:

$$ (\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j} \;=\; X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}$$

Now, I would like to understand why, in the case where we take "the covariant derivative of the component $V_{j}$ of the vector $V$", we get the expression :

$\nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{j})=X_{i}V_{j}$

i.e, the term $V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}$ has disappeared, compared to expression of $(\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j}$. It may be a confusion that I do between the 2 definitions ( $(\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j}$ and $\nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{j})$ ).

I thought that $\nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{j})$ also contained the shift caused by curvilinear coordinates changing during transport (represented by the second term $V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}$) : unfortunately, this idea seems to be wrong and expression $\nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{j})$ is just assimilated to $X_{i}V_{j}=\dfrac{\partial V_{j}}{\partial x^{i}}$.

Could you help me please to clarify this confusion and especially the differences or the links between the both definitions ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that $\nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{j})=X_{i}(V_{j})$ since $V_j$ is a function. Also, the identity $(\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j} \;=\; X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}$ is correct for a general vector $V$. But, you first identity $$\color{red}{(\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j} \;=\; \nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j} }\large(\text{which is   }  X_{i}(V_{j})\large) $$ is correct **only in flat spaces** where $\Gamma^{a}_{ij}$ vanish.

Comment: -@Semsem  thanks for your answer. Concerning my first identity, do you define (and more generally as a convention in litterature) $\color{red}{\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{j} \;=\; X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}}$ or $\color{red}{(\nabla_{X_{i}}V)_{j} \;=\; X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}}$ ? I mean, in which of these two terms do you consider $\Gamma_{ij}^{a}$ vanish ?

Comment: The first one is incorrect generally. The second one is correct and as a special case when the space is flat the second term of the RHS vanishes.